# Display xml content in html table columns

Tags: html, xml, html-table

I need to display following in each row of html table - 
xml doc1, xml doc2, text (1-15 lines max), couple of other small size columns.

If I use pre, xml looks mess. If I don't use pre, xml is all clubbed together which may be ok since its not going to look nice anyway.
I am thinking of using very small size font to display XMLs. Users can copy from html and paste in some editor if they want to see details.

And I want it to be responsive! I can let columns disappear if smaller size mainly xml ones.

I don't have any great css settings to get feedback on, so looking for help here...
itemDetails and references are xml content.

```
<table class="cssfortable">
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>ItemDetails</th>
        <th>References</th>
        <th>Verifications</th>
        <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="test,iterationStatus  : ${tests}">
        <td><pre th:utext="${iterationStatus.count}"></pre></td>
        <td><pre th:utext="${test.itemsDetails}"></pre></td>    
        <td><pre th:utext="${test.references}"></pre></td>
        <td><pre th:utext="${test.verifications}"></pre></td>
        <td><pre th:utext="${test.result}"></td>                                                                        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using following css shows fine except when I reduce screen size columns start to get cut off. Not a huge problem but if there is a more elegant way to display data please suggest.

```
#main table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
#main tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
#main th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
#main td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code or other example of what you're trying to solve.

Comment: Good formatted code makes it much more easy to read.